How to push my project to my git repo? Cannot find file that is too big
I tried to push but it returned me this error:

File jdk-22.0.1+8/lib/modules is 132.79 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

I attempted to use this command -> git rm jdk-22.0.1+8/lib/modules
I received this as feedback:

fatal: pathspec 'jdk-22.0.1+8/lib/modules' did not match any files

So I'm deeply confused because I'm unsure as to where this file is.
So far I've tried to set my HEAD back it is still showing the same error
I've tried to rm the file, but it returns as though it is not in the file
I've tried to manually search for the location of the file so that I can get rid of it or ignore it.

Duplicate of How can I remove/delete a large file from the commit history in the Git repository?

I ended up coming to the first commit and the issue was somewhere in there.

@ZackKier It would be better if you could check the link in the first comment and see if that answers your questions, and also if you found an answer by yourself please consider answering your question with a detailed explanation.
